# restrictive vs non-restrictive clause (that vs which)

Tags: word-usage, usage

Q1) Which institution had come to the narrator's town?

> 1. The institution which had come to the narrator's town was called Gaiety Land
> 2. The institution that had come to the narrator's town was called **the** Gaiety Land

Are there any rules to determine  whether the sentence is a restrictive or a non restrictive clause?

Comment: Firstly, both "that" and "which" are fine. The relative clause is clearly restrictive since it plays an essential role in defining which institution was called "Gaiety Land". Also, notice how the writer has purposely omitted a comma after "institution", which tells you that they intended it be restrictive. With restrictive relatives with non-human heads like your example, it's largely a free choice between "that" and "which". With non-restrictive relatives, however, only a _wh_ relative is possible ("Ed arrived late, which messed up our plans").

Comment: "Ed arrived late, which messed up our plans" can you please  elaborate by turning your example into a restrictive clause?

Comment: It's not possible to turn it into a restrictive clause because there is no noun phrase to act as an antecedent for "which". We could say "Ed arrived with the luggage [that/which he was given for Christmas]". In that example, the bracketed relative clause is restrictive, and you can choose either "that" or "which". It's a free choice.

Answer (score 1):

As BillJ mentions in his comment, both "that" and "which" are fine in this context.

So, focusing on the definite article "the":  since you are referring to a *named* entity (Gaiety Land) it is a proper noun.  In this case it's you must use the form by which it's commonly called.  For example:

> While visiting New York city, I went to the Empire State Building, the Statue of Liberty, and Times Square.
>
> While visiting Washington, D.C. we saw the White House, Capitol Hill, Arlington National Cemetery, and the Washington Monument.
>
> Next summer I plan to visit Australia, Singapore, Malaysia, and the Philippines.

I'm afraid that while there are some guidelines for this, there are no exact rules. As usual, repeat what you hear.

Answer (score 0):

British usage nearly always prefers **which**.  US usage varies, and
Writer's Digest gives this rule of thumb:  if the "which/that" clause is *extra information* that could be discarded, use **which**.  If it's basic information that cannot be discarded, use **that**.

The example they give is

> Our office, which has two lunchrooms, is located in Cincinnati.

Implicitly there's only one office and it's in Cincinnati.  The focus of the statement is the office's location. And we're provided the extra information that it has 2 lunchrooms.

> Our office that has two lunchrooms is located in Cincinnati.

Implicitly there are at least 2 offices, and the one that has 2 lunchrooms is in Cincinnati. The focus here is on the 2 lunchrooms, so it's basic information and can't be discarded.

See http://www.writersdigest.com/online-editor/which-vs-that

Your example 2 doesn't seem good to me, because when referring to a named entity, "the" shouldn't be used to prefix the name except at the beginning if there's some doubt about which of many entities is the one in question.  A good rule of thumb is "The earth is in trouble" or "Earth is in trouble", but **not** "The Earth is in trouble" because there is only one Earth.  Similarly, one wouldn't say "The Ayesha" unless as a lead-in to further identification:  "Which Ayesha are you talking about?" "The Ayesha who came over last Sunday" (or "Ayesha MacIntosh, Bill's GF").

Comment: No, restrictive relatives can have "that" or "which". It is normally a free choice.

Comment: Well, why don't you go tell Writer's Digest.  They write for a living.

Comment: You're being silly!

Comment: I can assure you that both "that" and "which" are fine. In BrE  too.

Comment: While you're at it, try http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/01/that-versus-which.html too

Comment: And while you're at it, try learning modern English grammar!